# Issue compiling with make -O

Tags: protocol-buffers, gnu-make, autoconf

We are having issues recompiling protobuf v2.6. It use to work and gmake would output the following:

```
...
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/atc/proto/protobuf-2.6.0/src'
depbase=`echo google/protobuf/compiler/main.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
/usr/bin/g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -pthread -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare  -m32 -MT google/protobuf/compiler/main.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o google/protobuf/compiler/main.o google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
depbase=`echo google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile /usr/bin/g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -pthread -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare  -m32 -MT google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.lo google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
...
```

Now it outputs the following and does not compile anything. All the .o files are 0bytes.

```
...
gmake[5]: Entering directory `/atc/proto/protobuf-2.6.0/src'
touch google/protobuf/compiler/.dirstamp
touch google/protobuf/compiler/.deps/.dirstamp
touch google/protobuf/compiler/main.o
touch google/protobuf/stubs/.dirstamp
touch google/protobuf/stubs/.deps/.dirstamp
touch google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.lo
...
```

We're hoping that someone with experience using google protobuf could explain why it is touching the files instead of compiling them. Knowing this we could probably quickly resolve the problem. We've got it building on another machine and we've been comparing everything we can think of but now we are at the point where we are going through the autoconf make files with a fine toothed comb to understand this behavior.

Our script that launches the google protobuff make is very simple and we've made no changes to the google protobuf (we only untar it and then build it).

**build_proto.sh**

```
set -x
pb_pkg=protobuf-2.6.0
cc=/usr/bin/g++
if [[ ! -e "$pb_pkg.tar.gz" ]]; then
    echo "Can't find $pb_pkg.tar.gz"
    exit
fi

tar xvfz $pb_pkg.tar.gz
cd $pb_pkg

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bb/bin/:/usr/bin
./configure CC=$cc CXX=$cc CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 FFLAGS=-m32 FCFLAGS=-m32
gmake
```

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    ./build_proto.sh
clean:
    rm -rf protobuf-2.6.0


build: all

test: all
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux atc-build 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 10:22:33 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update**

Issue is not in configure. Ran configure on its own and both systems' diffs were the same excluding trivial differences. Has to be in make.

Comment: Is there any reason for building 32bit binaries (`CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 FFLAGS=-m32 FCFLAGS=-m32`)? You are obviously running on 64bit (`x86_64`). Is there any reason for compiling at all? Modern Linux distributions mostly contain precompiled binary packages.

Comment: The answer to both questions is because of legacy debt. The other system builds fine with a target of 32bits and it is the same operating system so we know this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the result of two things. One of them in hindsight should have been an obvious warning sign in the system that was failing to build.

1. The top level make was being called with the -O flag.
2. the build_proto.sh was using gmake!

Switching the build_proto.sh from gmake to make fixed the issue. gmake didn't understand -O and so was having difficulty not only communicating back the output to make, but it apparently was running things in the wrong order (verbose output showed jobserver issues).